# Is binary search optimal in worst case?

Tags: algorithm, math, binary-search

Is binary search optimal in worst case? My instructor has said so, but I could not find a book that backs it up. We start with an ordered array, and in worst case(worst case for that algorithm), any algorithm will always take more **pairwise comparisons** than binary search.

Many people said that the question was unclear. Sorry! So the input is any general sorted array. I am looking for a proof which says that any search algorithm will take at least log2(N) comparisons in worst case(worst case for the algo in consideration).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search

Comment: What shall happen to all the answers that fail to address the actual question, i.e. they do not explain/proof *why* log2(N) is optimal for the worst-case of any algorithm ? I'm hesitating to downvote all the answers given so far..

Comment: I think you mean "at most log2(N) comparisons in worst case".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, binary search is optimal.

This is easily seen by appealing to information theory.  It takes `log N` bits merely to *identify* a unique element out of `N` elements.  But each comparison only gives you one bit of information.  Therefore, you must perform `log N` comparisons to identify a unique element.

More verbosely...  Consider a hypothetical algorithm X that outperforms binary search in the worst case.  For a particular element of the array, run the algorithm and *record* the questions it asks; i.e., the sequence of comparisons it performs.  Or rather, record the *answers* to those questions (like "true, false, false, true").

Convert that sequence into a binary string (1,0,0,1).  Call this binary string the "signature of the element with respect to algorithm X".  Do this for each element of the array, assigning a "signature" to each element.

Now here is the key.  If two elements have the same signature, then algorithm X cannot tell them apart!  All the algorithm knows about the array are the answers it gets from the questions it asks; i.e., the comparisons it performs.  And if the algorithm cannot tell two elements apart, then it cannot be correct.  (Put another way, if two elements have the same signature, meaning they result in the same sequence of comparisons by the algorithm, which one did the algorithm return?  Contradiction.)

Finally, prove that if every signature has fewer than `log N` bits, then there must exist two elements with the same signature (pigeonhole principle).  Done.

[update]

One quick additional comment.  The above assumes that the algorithm does not know anything about the array except what it learns from performing comparisons.  Of course, in real life, sometimes you do know something about the array *a priori*.  As a toy example, if I know that the array has (say) 10 elements all between 1 and 100, and that they are distinct, and that the numbers 92 through 100 are all present in the array...  Then clearly I do not need to perform four comparisons even in the worst case.

More realistically, if I know that the elements are uniformly distributed (or roughly uniformly distributed) between their min and their max, again I can do better than binary search.

But in the general case, binary search is still optimal.

Answer (score 6):

Worst case for which algorithm? There's not one universal "worst case." If your question is...

**"Is there a case where binary search takes more comparisons than another algorithm?"**

Then, yes, of course. A simple linear search takes less time if the element happens to be the first one in the list.

**"Is there even an algorithm with a better worst-case running time than binary search?"**

Yes, in cases where you know more about the data. For example, a radix tree or trie is at worst constant-time with regard to the number of entries (but linear in length of the key).

**"Is there a general search algorithm with a better worst-case running time than binary search?"**

If you can only assume you have a comparison function on keys, no, the best worst-case is O(log n). But there are algorithms that are faster, just not in a big-O sense.

... so I suppose you really would have to define the question first!

Comment: I meant the last case "Is there a general search algorithm with a better worst-case running time than binary search?". The input of course, is a sorted array. Also I am interested only in number of pairwise comparisons for the worst case(worst case for the given algo). Also link to a proof will be nice.

Comment: I don't have a proof handy, but the idea is that you're looking for the index of the element, which is a number with log2(n) bits. The most you can be sure to learn from one comparison is one bit, by comparing to the middle of the remaining list. So you'll need log_2(n) comparisons at least, in the worst case where the element isn't in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search has a worst case complexity of `O(log(N))` comparisons - which is optimal for a comparison based search of a sorted array.

In some cases it might make sense to do something other than a purely comparison based search - in this case you might be able to beat the `O(log(N))` barrier - i.e. check out [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) search.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the data. For example the English language and a dictionary. You could write an algorithm to achieve better than a binary search by making use of the fact that certain letters occur within the English language with different frequencies.

But in general a binary search is a safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is a little unclear, but still here are my thoughts.

Worst case of Binary search would be when the element you are searching for is found after all  log n comparisons. But the same data can be best case for linear search. It depends on the data arrangement and what you are searching for but the worst case for Binary search would end up to be log n. Now, this cannot be compared with same data and search for linear search since its worst case would be different. The worst case for Linear search could be finding an element which happens to be at the end of the array.

For example: array A = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and Binary Search on A for 1 would be the worst case. Whereas for the same array, linear search for 6 would be the worst case, not search for 1.