# showing that any algorithm that accesses an array only by comparisons takes sigma(logn) steps

Tags: arrays, algorithm

[image]

For this I think to properly solve it I need to show that sigma(logn) is its lower bound. I know all of the comparisons in my book run in O(nlogn), but im not sure how to form this into a concrete answer.

Comment: So far my plan is to explain the proof about how any comparison sort requries omega(nlogn) and then say since thats bigger than sigma(logn), logn is a suitable lower bound. I just feel there is a more concise way to put it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is binary search optimal in worst case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578709/is-binary-search-optimal-in-worst-case)

Comment: @Nemo: yeah, but that totally spoils the homework problem :) No peeking, jfisk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you've misread the problem: The array you are given is sorted. You are not sorting it. You are accessing it. Let's play a game. I pick a US state and you try to guess it. Every guess I will tell you if my chosen state is alphabetically before or after your guessed state. How many guesses do you need? The problem gives you a great clue with binary search.
2. Add this to your general algorithm toolbox: To show a lower bound is valid (but not necessarily tight), assume there exists an upper bound that is smaller, and do a proof by contradiction. For your problem, this should be doable.

Comment: Yes I did misread the problem, but I now see why the worst case is logn. Thanks!