# How many fewer questions can I ask to guess a number?

Tags: algorithm, math, puzzle, binary-search

If I ask a person to select a number between 1 and 1200 in his mind. If I can only ask questions for which he will only reply with YES or NO, how many questions will I need to ask before I arrive at the answer for the number He had selected in my mind ?

I am looking for the less possible number of questions. Any proven solution would be appreciable.

Answer (score 5):

To determine which of the numbers between 1 and n are chosen, you will need to ask at least log<sub>2</sub> n questions.  There is no possible way to do better.

The intuition for this answer is as follows.  Suppose that you ask a total of k questions.  The maximum number of different possible answers you can receive to those questions, even if they're dependent on one another, is 2<sup>k</sup>.  Since there are n possible numbers that could be picked, you need to choose k such that

> 2<sup>k</sup> ≥ n

Which happens precisely when

> k ≥ log<sub>2</sub> n

In other words, you have to ask at least log<sub>2</sub> n questions to be able to even have enough different possible outcomes to associate each possible number with some possible outcome.  Since the number of questions must always be a natural number, the minimum number of questions you can ask must be at least ⌈log<sub>2</sub> n⌉

This is purely a lower bound on the answer.  At this point, we can't rule out the possibility that maybe you need far more questions than this to get the answer.  However, the fact that we know about the binary search algorithm means that we know that you never need more than ⌈log<sub>2</sub> n⌉ questions to get the answer, since this is the number of questions you'd ask if you were doing a binary search.  This means that the binary search algorithm has to optimal, since there is no possible way of asking a smaller number of questions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ...and in order for the answer to be complete, the questions you ask are of the form: "is your number >= j/2?"

Answer (score 1):

The log base 2 of 1200, rounded up to an integer: that's 11.  Basically, every question cuts the possible range in half, so you just continue with a binary search until the possible range has length 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for all the bits in the number. 11 questions are enough for that.
Edit: I would argue, that it's impossible to do better, due to the bijectivity between the binary and decimal representation - at least for the worst case.

Comment: The number will have 11  bits. Hence, you can ask "Is the least significant bit 1?" and so on until you have your 11 bits.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen- This shows that it is *possible* to do this in 11 guesses, but it doesn't show what it's *impossible* to do better, which is the OP's question.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen -Sorry I din't understand that bit concept, can you please elaborate ? I appreciate your concern.

Comment: Oh. Well, *proof that it is optimal* is given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578709/is-binary-search-optimal-in-worst-case

Comment: @user1995408: if you have 11 bits, you can represent numbers from 0 to 2^11 -1 = 2047. Since you can ask everything that person, you can ask something like "is bit x equal 1". For example, let the number be 5. The binary representation is then 00000000101. If you would go then from the LSB to the MSB he would answer you YNYNNNNNNNN (by using the above question). With that you can know that it is 5. Binary search is in some way the same, just in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

This also a classical example of adversary arguments method which is used to find lower bound complexity. In our case the person who knows the number is the adversary. So he will wisely change his real answer when you ask a new question. How does he determine in his answer in each step? Let, for example the number is between 1-100.

You ask: is n>=50?. He may say YES OR NO both will be equally well for him since intervals are equal. Let assume he says yes.

Then you say a number between 50<=N<=100, lets say you ask: is n>=80.Then he should say NO even if the number he picked is larger than 80 because that 50<=n<=80 is larger interval.Now the number may be between 50 and 80

Maintaining this way, he will guarentee the maximum number of questions, that is logn since the interval size is decreasing like in binary search